# android:kotlin:DatePickerDialog set minDate and maxDate

Tags: android, kotlin

I want set minData and maxDate

```
val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this,
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
                    view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                Log.d("DatePickerDialog","$year-$month+1-$dayOfMonth")
                mDate[0]=year
                mDate[1]=month+1
                mDate[2]=dayOfMonth
            }, mDate[0],mDate[1]-1,mDate[2])
        val tmpmonth=afterDate[1]-1
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("$afterDate[0]-$tmpmonth-$afterDate[2]")
        val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm")
        val hee:Long=df.parse(datestr).time
        dpd.datePicker.maxDate(hee)            //<-----error
        dpd.show()
```

there is an error "maxDate is the type of Long can't be invoked as function, the function invoke() is not found"

```
// If I have value like this
//val year:Int=2019
//val month:Int=10
//val day:Int=14
//I want to change to Long

fun convert_YearMonthDay_to_Long(year:Int, month:Int, year:Int):Long{

//how?????

}
```

Comment: what do you mean you want to change to long? do you want to convert your year date month format to epoch time format?

Answer (score 0):

change this line of code  `dpd.datePicker.maxDate(hee)` to `dpd.datePicker.setMaxDate(hee)` or `dpd.datePicker.maxDate = hee` , it will work,
 `dpd.datePicker.maxDate` used to return the maxDate in long which is set to datepicker 
you want to set the date not to get it and 
this method need long value only and you are passing long value only

Answer (score -1):

You can use Long.toInt(), but it is not safe, you can use this:

```
fun Long.toIntOrNull(): Int? {
    val i = this.toInt()
    return if (i.toLong() == this) i else null
}
```

Comment: this answer is not relevant in the context of the question. There is no need for Long to Int conversion. even thou if required also then day, month,  year that mean a specific date need to be converted to long, for that @Doyeon Yeon need to set that info to the calendar and get the date as a Long value